# Interpreting effect sizes in cross-lagged -auto-regressive models

Tags: panel-data, autoregressive, lavaan

I am running an auto-regressive, cross-lagged panel model between three variables (individual survey responses) to understand the over-time dynamics between them. But I am trying to make sure I interpret my results correctly.

I am using a slightly modified version of the "standard" model based on this  [Hamaker et al 2015](https://doi.org/10.1037/a0038889) since I expect there to be trait-like characteristics. [Link to procedure](https://jflournoy.github.io/2017/10/20/riclpm-lavaan-demo/).

My main issue is judging the substantive significance of each variable, since most are statistically significant.

Results are "standardized" in lavaan.

The way I am interpreting these results is that, for example, the effect of `var2` on `pop1`  is less pronounced than the effect of `pop1` on `var2`. However, I am not confident, if I can talk about orders of magnitude etc.

Are there good references about

1. Ideas on how to make these results easily understood to the reader (who will not be too familiar with this method) ?
2. Contextualize/compare the coefficient estimates?

`Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
  pop1_w3 ~

    var1_w2 (ep_2)    0.062    0.032    1.942    0.052
    var2_w2 (zt_2)    0.115    0.030    3.831    0.000
    pop1_w2 (et_2)    1.043    0.023   44.534    0.000
  pop1_w2 ~

    var1_w1 (ep_1)    0.062    0.032    1.942    0.052
    var2_w1 (zt_1)    0.115    0.030    3.831    0.000
    pop1_w1 (et_1)    0.925    0.018   52.259    0.000
  var1_w3 ~

    var1_w2 (al_2)    0.047    0.026    1.828    0.068
    var2_w2 (bt_2)    0.092    0.021    4.323    0.000
    pop1_w2 (it_2)    0.296    0.019   15.498    0.000
  var1_w2 ~

    var1_w1 (al_1)    0.047    0.026    1.828    0.068
    var2_w1 (bt_1)    0.092    0.021    4.323    0.000
    pop1_w1 (it_1)    0.296    0.019   15.498    0.000
  var2_w3 ~

    var2_w2 (dl_2)    0.057    0.024    2.387    0.017
    var1_w2 (gm_2)    0.036    0.021    1.760    0.078
    pop1_w2 (kp_2)    0.233    0.019   12.403    0.000
  var2_w2 ~

    var2_w1 (dl_1)    0.057    0.024    2.387    0.017
    var1_w1 (gm_1)    0.036    0.021    1.760    0.078
    pop1_w1 (kp_1)    0.233    0.019   12.403`

And here are the summary statistics for each variable

```
       var1_w1       var1_w2         var1_w3         var2_w1          var2_w2          var2_w3          pop1_w1      
 Min.   : 0.0   Min.   : 0.000   Min.   : 0.000   Min.   : 0.000   Min.   : 0.000   Min.   : 0.000   Min.   : 0.000  
 1st Qu.: 4.0   1st Qu.: 3.000   1st Qu.: 3.000   1st Qu.: 2.000   1st Qu.: 2.000   1st Qu.: 2.000   1st Qu.: 0.000  
 Median : 6.0   Median : 6.000   Median : 5.000   Median : 4.000   Median : 4.000   Median : 4.000   Median : 3.000  
 Mean   : 5.9   Mean   : 5.456   Mean   : 5.316   Mean   : 4.228   Mean   : 4.176   Mean   : 3.898   Mean   : 4.158  
 3rd Qu.: 8.0   3rd Qu.: 8.000   3rd Qu.: 8.000   3rd Qu.: 6.000   3rd Qu.: 6.000   3rd Qu.: 6.000   3rd Qu.: 8.000  
 Max.   :10.0   Max.   :10.000   Max.   :10.000   Max.   :10.000   Max.   :10.000   Max.   :10.000   Max.   :10.000  
    pop1_w2          pop1_w3      
 Min.   : 0.000   Min.   : 0.000  
 1st Qu.: 0.000   1st Qu.: 0.000  
 Median : 3.000   Median : 3.000  
 Mean   : 4.087   Mean   : 4.179  
 3rd Qu.: 8.000   3rd Qu.: 8.000  
 Max.   :10.000   Max.   :10.000
```

Edit Note: The links apparently did not work, so I added links to the paper reference and the technical implementation in lavaan.

Answer (score 1):

One option to address your question is to use equality constraints. You can fit the model with the paths of interest constrained to be equal, and compare model fit against a model in which the target paths are freely estimated. If your `anova(model_constrained, model_unconstrained)` is not significant, then your simpler model (i.e., $>df$) is preferred as freeing the paths (i.e., making your model more complex) did not improve your data-model fit.

If I understand your model correctly you also have the option to calculate additional effects to assess direct, indirect, and total effects in you final model. The lavaan website provides instructions and some basic examples of how to use the syntax to accomplish both equality constraints and the partitioning of indirect/direct/total effects.

Lavaan Tutorial Site: 
http://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/index.html

Lavaan Tutorial Page on some advanced syntax (includes equality constraints): http://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/syntax2.html

Lavaan Tutorial Page on Mediation (for calculating direct, indirect, & total effects): http://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/mediation.html

Best of luck and I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Matt, thank you for the answer. I did constrain the model to equalize paths across time periods, and the model does not get worse. My main issue is more substantive: How do I argue that the path pop3--> Var2 is substantively more impactful than the path from Var2 --> Pop3? I am using the standardized solution, so I think I should be able to just compare coefficient sizes, but I am unsure, hence my question.

Comment: Maybe it is a typo but are you saying that you have pop3 --> var2 and var2 --> pop3 in the same model (not advisable)? Or do you want to somehow show that the path going in one direction in one model is better/stronger/different than the same path in reverse in a separate model?

Comment: Hi Matt. I should have been more precise. Since this is a panel model I want to compare cross-lags and auto-regressive Paths. So I want to see how the path from Var2 (t1) --> Pop1 (t2) compares to the path Pop1(t1) --> Var2(t2). 

I just realized that the links I had included to explain the underlying technique/the paper I am basing this on did not work. I have added them for reference.

Comment: Okay, I understand your question better now. If the variables are measured on the same scale then you sort of have your answer already. The two paths do not significantly differ. You could standardize your variables to ensure that your paths are in reference to the exact same range of scores (i.e., a one-unit change means the same thing for each distribution) and then constrain them to be equal, but unless the distributions are very different you'll probably get the same finding. You can compare standardized regression weights descriptively, but hypothesis testing yields no difference.